# C++ primitive type safety

Tags: c++, type-safety

Is there any computational overhead by implementing class wrapper to ensure type-safety on C primitive types? And if not, why those wrapper are not in the STL?

```
#include <iostream>

template< typename T >
class Safe
{
    template<typename K>
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream&, const Safe<K>& );

public:

    using Type = T;

    Safe( ) = default;

    explicit Safe(const T& value) : m_value(value){}

    Safe<T> operator +(const Safe<T>& other) const;
    Safe<T> operator -(const Safe<T>& other) const;
    Safe<T> operator *(const Safe<T>& other) const;
    Safe<T> operator /(const Safe<T>& other) const;
    Safe<T> operator %(const Safe<T>& other) const;

private:
    T m_value;
};

template<typename T>
inline Safe<T> Safe<T>::operator +(const Safe<T>& other) const
{
    return Safe<T>( this->m_value + other.m_value );
}

template<typename T>
inline Safe<T> Safe<T>::operator -(const Safe<T>& other) const
{
    return Safe<T>( this->m_value - other.m_value );
}

template<typename T>
inline Safe<T> Safe<T>::operator *(const Safe<T>& other) const
{
    return Safe<T>( this->m_value * other.m_value );
}

template<typename T>
inline Safe<T> Safe<T>::operator /(const Safe<T>& other) const
{
    return Safe<T>( this->m_value / other.m_value );
}

template<typename T>
inline Safe<T> Safe<T>::operator %(const Safe<T>& other) const
{
    return Safe<T>( this->m_value % other.m_value );
}

template<typename T>
inline std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const Safe<T>& number)
{
    return os << number.m_value;
}

using Int8 = Safe<std::int8_t>;
using Int16 = Safe<std::int16_t>;
using Int32 = Safe<std::int32_t>;
using Int64 = Safe<std::int64_t>;

using UInt8 = Safe<std::uint8_t>;
using UInt16 = Safe<std::uint16_t>;
using UInt32 = Safe<std::uint32_t>;
using UInt64 = Safe<std::uint64_t>;

using Int = Safe<signed int>;
using UInt = Safe<unsigned int>;

int main(int, char *[])
{
    Int32 a(5);
    Int32 b(2);
    Int64 ehi(5);
    Int64 bee(2);

    const auto c = a + b;
    const auto see = ehi + bee;

    /* will not compile: */
    /* const auto result = a + bee; */

    std::cout << c << std::endl;
    std::cout << see << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try it. You'll quickly discover why this is a non-starter.

Comment: Why is int32+int32 "safe"?  Hint: it's not.

Comment: It would become tedious very fast to always cast whenever you need numeric promotion (which is quite a convenient thing to have)

Comment: I'm willing to bet there is no overhead.  But often the best way to tell is to test it yourself.

Comment: @StoryTeller One could bake integer promotion in the cases where it is safe (i.e. if you add a a 32 bit into to a 64 bit one the 64 bit could do the promotion of the 32 bit)

Comment: @Borgleader, yes but you don't get it for free here as you do with the buil-in types. It would take *a lot* of boiler-plate to achieve it again, if it's at all possible

Comment: @StoryTeller I think promotion criteria can all be coded as compile time type traits with, no runtime overhead. The aim is type safety, and not writing less code. Sometimes writing code more makes the programmer more aware of the operation that (s)he is coding.

Comment: You really need a lot to make it work. For example, converting ints to doubles are usually considered quite safe. You need to be able to compare different numeric types as well. Promotions were already mentioned. signed/unsigned conversions are going to be required (unfortunately). Etc.

Comment: @StoryTeller Not sure what you mean by "you dont get it for free", [foo() and bar() end up being the same](https://godbolt.org/g/LsswI0), but then again maybe my test case is incorrect. I'm not saying it wouldn't be a lot of work, but I think it's theoretically possible?

Comment: @Borgleader, taking a lot of work, is kind of the opposite of getting it for free.

Comment: @StoryTeller Oh I thought you meant free as in performance cost.

Comment: @Borgleader No, I'm sure an optimizing compiler can rip right thorough all the boiler-plate. I was indeed referring to the time required to write all that boiler-plate code.

Comment: Disallowing all implicit conversions will get you nowhere fast. Disallowing implicit narrowing conversions may be a good thing but compilers tend to warn you about them anyway. Making the set of allowed conversions customizable sounds interesting in theory, but please, for sanity sake, no.

Comment: Robert Ramey has proposed [such a library](https://github.com/robertramey/safe_numerics) for Boost. He also gave a [talk about its design at CppCon 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cw_8QkFXZjI&list=PLHTh1InhhwT7J5jl4vAhO1WvGHUUFgUQH&index=96).

Answer (score 0):

The overhead is massive since every single operation can potentially overflow and only rarely will the compiler be able to optimise your checks out. Which is basically why range-checked types are not in the STL. Ada does apply such checks, and they were built into the language from the very start, it's not something that is impossible or inherently a bad idea.

But as others have said, it's not a good fit for C++. If you must do it, I advise that all data is held as doubles and not allowed to go beyond the range +/-FTL_MAX, and FLT_EPSILON is clamped to zero. All indices hold as signed int and be very careful in clamping to INT_MAX.

Comment: Do you see any range checks in the proposed wrapper?